# IE spread operator and destructuring not supported

Tags: javascript, operator-keyword, destructuring, spread

I'm new to programming and I've just stumbled upon a problem that I don't fully understand yet. 
I've looked everywhere for similar problems and their resolution but 
but I don't see how I can fix this problem. 
So I'm asking for your help to know the best way to do this code without the spread operator and destructuring that are not functional in IE.

Here the code I have and what i need to adapt to be functional on IE 11:

```
computed: {
            quantityValues: function () {
                return [...Array(5).keys()].map(function (v) { return v + this.currentQuantity + 1; }.bind(this));
            }
        }
```

Thank you all in advance for your answers.

Comment: There's no destructuring in that code. To replace the spread syntax, use `Array.from`.

Comment: There is more than the spread operator that is not supported in that by IE 11

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I'll try that.

Comment: @Bergi Array.from is edge

Answer (score 0):

For IE you need to rewrite your code avoiding usage of the spread operator or to use a babel plugin that will do it for you: https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-transform-es2015-spread.

```js
var a = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
var b = [...a, 'foo'];

var a = [ 'a', 'b', 'c' ];
var b = [].concat(a, [ 'foo' ]);
```

in your case it means

```js
computed: {
            quantityValues: function () {
                return Array(5).keys().concat().map(function (v) { return v + this.currentQuantity + 1; }.bind(this));
            }
        }
```

but for the `.keys()` I wouldn't say you need a spread operator, because `Array(5)` already creates a unique instance: `Array(5).keys().map...` would fit.

Answer (score 0):

```
computed: {
    quantityValues: function () {
        var arr = [];
        for(var i = 0; i < 5; i += 1) {
          arr.push(i + this.currentQuantity + 1)
        }
        return arr;
    }
}
```

Does this help?

Answer (score 0):

Spread and keys are not supported in IE11 so you would have to replace it will fill

```
quantityValues: function () {
  var currentQuantity = this.currentQuantity 
  return new Array(5)
    .fill(undefined)
    .map(function (v, i) { 
      return i + currentQuantity + 1; 
    });
}
```